What is name of this diode (marking SL 1T)?
I have vaccum cleaner and a few days ago, it doesn’t work at all. I dismantled its plastic case and I finally found that a diode, which located in laser lidar sensor's PCB and which is written "SL 1T" on its surface, have been shorted.
But I don't know what is the name of this diode.
Is there anyone know what is name of this diode?


There are multiple diodes which have a marking of SL according to the The ultimate SMD marking codes database, of types Diode, Transient voltage supressor or Zener diode. To help identify the device can you edit the question to include (a) dimensions of the diode (b) a photo which shows the surrounding devices to help give context.

You’ll want to desolder that diode and confirm that it indeed is shorted out of circuit, and confirm that it doesn’t behave like a diode anymore. Schottkeys when measured in conductive direction can look like very low resistance on a multimeter. They should still be open or almost open in the reverse direction. If it is shorted for real, then replace it with a similar size power Schottky and see what happens. The thing is dead anyway, may as well try a few benign things.

Thank you very much for reply! I desoldered this diode and It seems that it is not shoted, and I resoldered it to laser lidar sensor's PCB and I noticed that it was measured shorted diode whenever I connected Female Connector of Motor which is the same kind of motor as aliexpress link. aliexpress.com/item/33026820457.html

Probably 1N5819HW from Diodes Inc.
Marking code "SL", "1T" is a date code.
Picture from LCSC:

Please check dimensions to confirm that it is a SOD-123.

Thank you very much for reply!
I desoldered this diode and It seems that it is not shoted, and I resoldered it to laser lidar sensor's PCB and I noticed that it was measured shorted diode whenever I connected Female Connector of Motor which is the same kind of motor as aliexpress link.
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33026820457.html

The link is jlcpcb not LCSC

@SnappyRiffs JLCPCB and LCSC are affiliated, and I think might even be two brands of the same company.

even then, your link goes to jlcpcb and not lcsc even though you said 'Picture from LCSC'
